# Azure Automation Runbook stops working randomly

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-automation

I have a Azure Automation Runbook written in Powershell. It takes a SQL DB every week and creates a backup to blob storage. This has been working for over a year and abruptly stopped producing .bacpac files to blob last month.

Nothing appears to be wrong with the code as it has not changed and running it in the test pane with the proper parameters, which have also remained unchanged, completes successfully. When the scheduler calls the job, the runbook is called and runs with no errors or warnings, just does not produce the .bacpac file to blob storage.

Has anyone run into this problem or similar? I am looking for suggestions on where to be checking within portal, sql or wherever to resolve this issue. I cannot seem to find the problematic moment via activity log.

Comment: did you check sys.event_log to see any indications of errors

Comment: Also azure automation has an option to enable verbose logs,did you try enabling them .See this for info :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages

Comment: where can I find the sys.event_log? thank you for the quick response. I enabled verbose logging but won't be able to see that until the process finishes, i'm running it manually but it takes about 6 hours.

Comment: It is a dmv in sqlserver ,query for any kind of logs during the failure time frame

Comment: checked the sys.event_log and everything is successful for the duration of the runbook job

Comment: UPDATE: I found this failure error -

 Error encountered during the service operation. One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
Error 0: An error occurred while attempting to reverse engineer elements of type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlColumnStoreIndex: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlView' to type 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlTableBase'.

Any help on the issue is appreciated